# Why is this quoted tweet pointing to itself?

Tags: twitter, twitter-rest-api

I am retrieving tweets with the Twitter API and I do this:
I check that they have a quoted_status, then I replace the URL in `url_info->url` that has the `tweet_data->quoted_status->id_str` within the `url_info->expanded_url`. This way, I know the URL is the one of the quoted tweet, and I can recover the data and display it below.

And this usually works, but not with this tweet:

```
stdClass Object
(
[created_at] => Wed Dec 14 08:30:32 +0000 2016
[id] => 8.0895229853789E+17
[id_str] => 808952298537885696
[text] => Volem felicitar al Centre d'Estudis Montseny, guanyadors d'aquest concurs, i a @stlisieux, que han estat finalistesâ€¦ 'shortened_url'/CGqkTNPPB1
[truncated] => 1
[entities] => stdClass Object
    (
        [hashtags] => Array
            (
            )

        [symbols] => Array
            (
            )

        [user_mentions] => Array
            (
                [0] => stdClass Object
                    (
                        [screen_name] => stlisieux
                        [name] => ColÂ·legi ST Lisieux
                        [id] => 3064329677
                        [id_str] => 3064329677
                        [indices] => Array
                            (
                                [0] => 79
                                [1] => 89
                            )

                    )

            )

        [urls] => Array
            (
                [0] => stdClass Object
                    (
                        [url] => 'shortened_url'CGqkTNPPB1
                        [expanded_url] => https://twitter.com/i/web/status/808952298537885696
                        [display_url] => twitter.com/i/web/status/8â€¦
                        [indices] => Array
                            (
                                [0] => 117
                                [1] => 140
                            )

                    )

            )

    )

[source] => Twitter Web Client
[in_reply_to_status_id] => 
[in_reply_to_status_id_str] => 
[in_reply_to_user_id] => 
[in_reply_to_user_id_str] => 
[in_reply_to_screen_name] => 
[user] => stdClass Object
    (
        [id] => 493037120
        [id_str] => 493037120
        [name] => Clickedu
        [screen_name] => Clickedu
        [location] => EspaÃ±a
        [description] => La plataforma para colegios e institutos. | La plataforma per a escoles i instituts. 'shortened_url'/NBZbqw7Qpn
        [url] => 'shortened_url'/00a8v8WUv5
        [entities] => stdClass Object
            (
                [url] => stdClass Object
                    (
                        [urls] => Array
                            (
                                [0] => stdClass Object
                                    (
                                        [url] => 'shortened_url'/00a8v8WUv5
                                        [expanded_url] => http://www.clickartedu.com/
                                        [display_url] => clickartedu.com
                                        [indices] => Array
                                            (
                                                [0] => 0
                                                [1] => 22
                                            )

                                    )

                            )

                    )

                [description] => stdClass Object
                    (
                        [urls] => Array
                            (
                                [0] => stdClass Object
                                    (
                                        [url] => 'shortened_url'/NBZbqw7Qpn
                                        [expanded_url] => http://www.clickedu.eu
                                        [display_url] => clickedu.eu
                                        [indices] => Array
                                            (
                                                [0] => 85
                                                [1] => 107
                                            )

                                    )

                            )

                    )

            )

        [protected] => 
        [followers_count] => 2960
        [friends_count] => 1998
        [listed_count] => 79
        [created_at] => Wed Feb 15 11:29:55 +0000 2012
        [favourites_count] => 8529
        [utc_offset] => 3600
        [time_zone] => Madrid
        [geo_enabled] => 1
        [verified] => 
        [statuses_count] => 3840
        [lang] => ca
        [contributors_enabled] => 
        [is_translator] => 
        [is_translation_enabled] => 
        [profile_background_color] => AD0C40
        [profile_background_image_url] => http://pbs.twimg.com/profile_background_images/444501732022697984/vMM1qgYt.jpeg
        [profile_background_image_url_https] => https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_background_images/444501732022697984/vMM1qgYt.jpeg
        [profile_background_tile] => 
        [profile_image_url] => http://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/567973366670172160/1opAPyhE_normal.jpeg
        [profile_image_url_https] => https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/567973366670172160/1opAPyhE_normal.jpeg
        [profile_banner_url] => https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_banners/493037120/1477042035
        [profile_link_color] => AD0C40
        [profile_sidebar_border_color] => FFFFFF
        [profile_sidebar_fill_color] => DDEEF6
        [profile_text_color] => 333333
        [profile_use_background_image] => 1
        [has_extended_profile] => 
        [default_profile] => 
        [default_profile_image] => 
        [following] => 
        [follow_request_sent] => 
        [notifications] => 
        [translator_type] => none
    )

[geo] => 
[coordinates] => 
[place] => 
[contributors] => 
[is_quote_status] => 1
[quoted_status_id] => 8.0870805032451E+17
[quoted_status_id_str] => 808708050324508672
[quoted_status] => stdClass Object
    (
        [created_at] => Tue Dec 13 16:19:58 +0000 2016
        [id] => 8.0870805032451E+17
        [id_str] => 808708050324508672
        [text] => AixÃ­ Ã©s com veuen lâ€™ictus els alumnes del Centre dâ€™Estudis Montseny, que han guanyat el 18Ã¨ concurs Pinta La MaratÃ³â€¦ 'shortened_url'/tts4uGmKWy
        [truncated] => 1
        [entities] => stdClass Object
            (
                [hashtags] => Array
                    (
                    )

                [symbols] => Array
                    (
                    )

                [user_mentions] => Array
                    (
                    )

                [urls] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => stdClass Object
                            (
                                [url] => 'shortened_url'/tts4uGmKWy
                                [expanded_url] => https://twitter.com/i/web/status/808708050324508672
                                [display_url] => twitter.com/i/web/status/8â€¦
                                [indices] => Array
                                    (
                                        [0] => 117
                                        [1] => 140
                                    )

                            )

                    )

            )

        [source] => Twitter Web Client
        [in_reply_to_status_id] => 
        [in_reply_to_status_id_str] => 
        [in_reply_to_user_id] => 
        [in_reply_to_user_id_str] => 
        [in_reply_to_screen_name] => 
        [user] => stdClass Object
            (
                [id] => 18045654
                [id_str] => 18045654
                [name] => La MaratÃ³
                [screen_name] => la_marato
                [location] => Catalunya
                [description] => El 18 de desembre La MaratÃ³ fa 25 anys amb un programa dedicat a l'ictus i les lesions medulÂ·lars i cerebrals traumÃ tiques.
                [url] => 'shortened_url'/iCXlb20x3w
                [entities] => stdClass Object
                    (
                        [url] => stdClass Object
                            (
                                [urls] => Array
                                    (
                                        [0] => stdClass Object
                                            (
                                                [url] => 'shortened_url'/iCXlb20x3w
                                                [expanded_url] => http://www.tv3.cat/marato/
                                                [display_url] => tv3.cat/marato/
                                                [indices] => Array
                                                    (
                                                        [0] => 0
                                                        [1] => 22
                                                    )

                                            )

                                    )

                            )

                        [description] => stdClass Object
                            (
                                [urls] => Array
                                    (
                                    )

                            )

                    )

                [protected] => 
                [followers_count] => 46627
                [friends_count] => 352
                [listed_count] => 333
                [created_at] => Thu Dec 11 11:38:21 +0000 2008
                [favourites_count] => 1469
                [utc_offset] => 3600
                [time_zone] => Madrid
                [geo_enabled] => 
                [verified] => 
                [statuses_count] => 3160
                [lang] => ca
                [contributors_enabled] => 
                [is_translator] => 
                [is_translation_enabled] => 
                [profile_background_color] => DCE4E8
                [profile_background_image_url] => http://pbs.twimg.com/profile_background_images/378800000099697740/e6dc40b2a9233a582dc14394aed732a7.jpeg
                [profile_background_image_url_https] => https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_background_images/378800000099697740/e6dc40b2a9233a582dc14394aed732a7.jpeg
                [profile_background_tile] => 
                [profile_image_url] => http://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/748843776345513985/WXSEA15G_normal.jpg
                [profile_image_url_https] => https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/748843776345513985/WXSEA15G_normal.jpg
                [profile_banner_url] => https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_banners/18045654/1481702408
                [profile_link_color] => 0084B4
                [profile_sidebar_border_color] => FFFFFF
                [profile_sidebar_fill_color] => DDEEF6
                [profile_text_color] => 333333
                [profile_use_background_image] => 1
                [has_extended_profile] => 
                [default_profile] => 
                [default_profile_image] => 
                [following] => 
                [follow_request_sent] => 
                [notifications] => 
                [translator_type] => none
            )

        [geo] => 
        [coordinates] => 
        [place] => 
        [contributors] => 
        [is_quote_status] => 
        [retweet_count] => 15
        [favorite_count] => 21
        [favorited] => 
        [retweeted] => 
        [possibly_sensitive] => 
        [lang] => und
    )

[retweet_count] => 2
[favorite_count] => 2
[favorited] => 
[retweeted] => 
[possibly_sensitive] => 
[lang] => und
)
```

Here, the `[expanded_url] => https://twitter.com/i/web/status/808952298537885696` is pointing to the tweet itself, not to the quoted tweet as usual.

Is this common? 
How can I link the shortened URL in the text body with the quoted tweet? I don't see any connexion between them, so I don't know how to replace the link for the tweet content, as I don't know how to differentiate the quoted tweet URL from other URLs that may be in the tweet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the `truncated` value in this Tweet is `true` (1), this indicates that you are looking at an extended Tweet. You can read more about the new Tweet format in the Twitter developer [Upcoming Changes to Tweets](https://dev.twitter.com/overview/api/upcoming-changes-to-tweets) documentation. If you use the `tweet_mode=extended` option you will be able to retrieve the full Tweet without the embedded link to the web version of the Tweet.